# Salesforce: Update Managed Object's Auto number Field...

Tags: salesforce, force.com

I would like to know if we can update auto number field. When I tried updating using Dev Console system said : 'Field is not Writable'

In our support product(Managed Package), I need to update/ start auto number field from specific number say 100.

I am thinking of creating a text field and imitate is as that Auto Number field. But I don't know how much will it hamper existing functionality of the package.

Any idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How will you avoid the conflict of the auto-increment trying to use a value manually entered?  I ask that not because you can do it with an auto-increment, but because you can implement your own auto-increment using a trigger, but will have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cant set new values to auto number fields in Salesforce. But you can use for this custom field with number type, which will be automatically filled in using the trigger. In the trigger you can implement any logic to check the uniqueness of fields and check all its conditions. If you want input values of this field manually, you can use validation rules for checking the uniqueness.